# Can "wandering eye" be used as a biblical reference or as marriage issue?

Tags: expressions

In a [series](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=scandal&episode=s03e06) I've heard someone refer to *wandering eye* as an example of problems in a marriage.

> - What kind of problems?
>   - He's got a wandering eye, evidently.
>   - So Ms. Bible Bully and I do have something in common after all.

Since the speaker, in fact, seems to have nothing in common with the mentioned woman (the bully), I'm not sure what they mean.

The best shot I have is that they refer to infidelity, as this is the most significant property of the president's marriage. However, I feel I'm missing something.

Comment: You are very close to the meaning, I think.  Did you google [wandering eye](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+wandering+eye)?

Comment: @stangdon Even if I'm close to the meaning in my guess (which I still claim seems quite far fetched for me to be regarded as an estimation, let alone a fact), I still can't see how or why it fits, so I'd welcome an elaboration on the subject. As for googling, I only got hits on medical terms of [*strabismus*](http://www.strabismus.org/strabismus_crossed_eyes.html) (which apparently is fancy talk for being cross-eyed). And, obviously, that's not it.

Comment: @stangdon I just re-googled it on my phone and here's what I've found. This **can't** be right, can it?! "*...a wandering eye is a vagina that has moved from its original place (a prolapse). It most commonly happens with women that have just had children or with old ladies that are severely disappointed with their grandchildren...*"

Comment: @KonradViltersten That definition's got 21 thumbs up, 49 thumbs down. I think there's nothing biblical at all in that part of the dialogue. It's just that someone was called Ms.BB; that's all. (I don't watch that show, by the way.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yeah, I figured out that there was something fishy with that definition. I was viewing it on my phone so it was hard to get a full grasp of the surrounding texts/icons - didn't even see any thumbs, to be honest. I was just making clear to one of the users that I **did indeed** google it prior to asking here. I got a sense that they suspected I didn't do the obvious research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - (person 1) What kind of problems?
>   - (person 2) He's got a [wandering eye](http://www.yourtango.com/200922292/men-relationships-still-have-wandering-eye), evidently.
>   - (person 1) So Ms. Bible Bully and I do have something in common after all.

When a man is said to "have a wandering eye" it is an idiom meaning that he looks at or watches other women. Typically in front of the spouse which causes marital problems.

The implication here seems to be that person 1 is a woman, and that the "he" referred to by person 2 is married (or in a relationship) to Ms. Bible Bully. So person 1 is saying in addition that she has the "wandering eye" problem with her mate/husband.

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure it's causing **martial** problems? Or did you mean **matrimonial**, by any chance? Of course, if the spouse is a violent person, it could technically lead to martial outcome... Also, on a more serious note, is that something exclusive to **men** gazing at **women**? Is it applicable to women looking at men? How about men looking at men and women looking at women (in a homosexual case)?

Comment: I fixed person1/person2 in second paragraph. // martial = matrimonial, // Yes in this day and age gay relationships are possible. Person 2 could be a man or a woman. But person 1 seems to be identifying with Ms. Bully which would be odd for a man.

Comment: Teehee - you spelled **martial** in your comment. I know what you mean but it's kind of funny how easily misspelled the word is. Maybe you're unconsciously thinking of a violent resolution to such a looking by martial arts, hehe. I'm awarding you a martial +1 for effort.

Comment: LOL - no the word should have been marital not martial. // I can't type worth a flip. Two deformed little fingers meant that high school typing class was no good for me. Add that to being a poor speller in general and spell check is my best friend. I obviously don't proofread carefully enough either...